# How does this overloading of square brackets work

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators, string-literals, square-bracket

I want to avoid printing space (" ") or an underscore ("_") after the last element of an array while printing them using a for loop. The problem mentions one of the way to do so, I want to understand how and why this happens.

```
    vector<int> v1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int n = v1.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << v1[i] << "_"[i==n-1];
    }
```

this prints 1_2_3_4_5 which is as expected.

I want to get around the working of this operator. How it functions and what other aspects does it cover.

Comment: It is just an implementation of the subscript operator on vector (not even overloading). And vector must allocate a contiguous piece of memory. So it is just a matter of calculating the offset into memory and return an element found there. Maybe this will help you https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/overloading-the-subscript-operator/

Comment: I recommend you invest in [some good beginners C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) as they will explain all that (and *much* more).

Comment: Print out `"_"[0]` and `"_"[1]`.  What do you get?

Comment: I'm not sure it's good to print `\0`, maybe it should be `"_" + (i==n-1)`, still not recommend though.

Comment: What that outputs depends on which medium it's outputting on – some terminals display the null character as "nothing", but that's not guaranteed to happen.

Comment: There's no magic to the overloading. A boolean can be converted to an integer; `false` to 0, and `true` to 1. So that's the same as `int index = i==n-1 ? 1 : 0; cout << v1[i] << "_"[index];`

Comment: Refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) where the first step is to *"search and then research"* and you'll find plenty of dupes for this.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, you example was to the point, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing special going on with `[]` here. Its the usual element access. `"_"` is a `const char [2]` where first character is `_` and the second is a null terminator `\0`.

You could do the same with a string:

```
vector<int> v1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int n = v1.size();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cout << v1[i] << std::string{"_"}[i==n-1];
}
```

Note, that `std::string` is an excepetion among containers and it is ok to read the `\0` from `str[str.size()]`.

`\0` is not a printable character, hence you see the output you see.

Perhaps the code more clear if you use an empty string explicitly:

```
vector<int> v1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
std::vector<std::string> d{ "_",""};
int n = v1.size();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cout << v1[i] << d[i==n-1];
}
```

Alternatively, as you are using an index based loop anyhow (rather than a range based loop, which should be prefered), you can start the loop at the second element:

```
std::vector<int> v1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
std::vector<std::string> d{ "_",""};
int n = v1.size();
if (n) std::cout << v1[0];
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    std::cout << "_" << v1[i];
}
```

Comment: *"`"_"` is a `char [2]`..."* No it is not

Comment: it can also be `&"_"[condition]`

Answer (score 1):

In this statement

```
cout << v1[i] << "_"[i==n-1];
```

the expression `"_"[i==n-1]` is an expression with the string literal `"_"`.

String literals have types of constant character arrays. The literal `"_"` has the type `const char[2]` and is represented in memory like

```
{ '_', '\0' }
```

So the expression `"_"[i==n-1]` uses the subscript operator with the string literal that is with an array. The expression `i == n-1` is always equal to `false` that is converted to integer `0`  when `i` is not equal to `n-1`. Otherwise it is equal to `true` that is converted to `1`.

So you have either `"_"[0]`  that yields the character `'_'` or `"_"[1]` that yields the character `'\0';`.

That is when `i` is not equal to `n-1` you in fact have

```
cout << v1[i] << '_';
```

and when `i` is equal to `n -1` you in fact have

```
cout << v1[i] << '\0';
```

Pay attention to that in this expression `"_"[i==n-1]`  the string literal is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element.

Alternatively you could write with the same effect

```
vector<int> v1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int n = v1.size();
const char literal[] = "_";
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cout << v1[i] << literal[i==n-1];
}
```

To enlarge your knowledge bear in mind that this expression `"_"[i==n-1]`  you may also rewrite like `( i == n-1 )["_"]` though such an expression will only confuse readers of the code.

From the C++17 Standard (8.2.1 Subscripting)

> 1 A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets is
> a postfix expression. One of the expressions shall be a glvalue of
> type “array of T” or a prvalue of type “pointer to T” and the other
> shall be a prvalue of unscoped enumeration or integral type. The
> result is of type “T”. The type “T” shall be a completely-defined
> object type.66 The expression E1[E2] is identical (by definition) to
> *((E1)+(E2)) [ Note: see 8.3 and 8.7 for details of * and + and 11.3.4 for details of arrays. — end note ] , except that in the case of an
> array operand, the result is an lvalue if that operand is an lvalue
> and an xvalue otherwise. The expression E1 is sequenced before the
> expression E2.

Pay attention to that this code snippet

```
vector<int> v1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int n = v1.size();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cout << v1[i] << "_"[i==n-1];
}
```

could look more clear using the range-based for loop. For example

```
std::vector<int> v1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

bool next = false;
for ( const auto &item : v1 ) 
{
    if ( next ) std::cout << '_';
    else next = true; 

    std::cout << item;
}
```

If the compiler supports the C++20 Standard then you can write also like

```
std::vector<int> v1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

for ( bool next = false; const auto &item : v1 ) 
{
    if ( next ) std::cout << '_';
    else next = true; 

    std::cout << item;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, this did clear the doubt.

Answer (score 0):

your problem has nothing todo with the subscript operator though
you just need to figure out when to print the _ or not based on the position in the array when printing.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
    
// using namespace std; ehr no don't do this
  
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
   
    for (std::size_t i{ 0ul }; i < v1.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (i != 0ul) std::cout << "_";
        std::cout << v1[i];
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
   
    // with vector use range based for if you can
    // and then it becomes
    bool print_underscore = false;
    
    for (const int value : v1)
    {
        if (print_underscore) std::cout << "_";
        std::cout << value;
        print_underscore = true;
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    
    return 0;
}
```